# centralized alternative for get_option: get_site_option, get_network_option or get_site_meta?

Tags: options

When storing option for current-site (sub-site), we use `get_option`, however, when we want to have one centralized option (which should apply to all sub-sites, including the primary sub-site), which one is better to be used:

- [{get/update}_site_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_option/)
- [{get/update}_network_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_network_option/)
- [{get/set}_site_meta](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/01/28/multisite-support-for-site-metadata-in-5-1/)

so, in case the host is not Multi_Site, the function should automatically fallback to current site's option (as `get_options` does).

Comment: (get/update)_site_option() is simply a wrapper for (get/update)_network_option() which falls back to (get/update)_option() when `is_multisite()` returns `false`. So the answer is probably the (get/update)_site_option() function.

Comment: @SallyCJ you could have posted it as answer !  (btw, get_site_meta? )

Comment: `get_site_meta` is part of the 5.1 release, which hasn't happened yet.  I would avoid that for now.